# How to change default execution time of ConfigClusterResolver

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I setup a sample Spring Cloud Gateway project which is running fine.
But I noticed that it updates the endpoints fetching data from Eureka server each 5 minutes.
When it happens it prints the follow:

```
c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
```

Does anyone know how to change the default time of 5 minutes?

I tried to add to application.yml the follow property but the update remained on the default value of 5 minutes

```
eureka.client.registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 5
```

Also some filters was added to but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Sadlly, it is hard coded, check EurekaClientConfigBean for more info.

```
public int getEurekaServiceUrlPollIntervalSeconds() {
    return this.eurekaServiceUrlPollIntervalSeconds;
}

private int eurekaServiceUrlPollIntervalSeconds = 5 * MINUTES;
```

But you may change it by adding config in eureka.client.properties.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(EurekaClientConfigBean.PREFIX)
public class EurekaClientConfigBean implements EurekaClientConfig, Ordered {

/**
 * Default prefix for Eureka client config properties.
 */
public static final String PREFIX = "eureka.client";
```